# Can too many tags make wordpress site go slow?

Tags: wordpress, web, tags, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress site with 5000 to 6000 visitor per day.
I have dedicated vps hosting 
2 GB RAM 
2 CPU Cores
4.8 GHz Total CPU Power
80 GB SSD Disk Space

but it is too slow at some point.
even sometimes it says busy.
when i check using c panel it shows all ram and processors has been used with red mark alert sign.

I haves used too many tags on most of my post is it because of that "am guessing".
As,once I made one post with nearly 1000 tags, while posting it, the whole server was down so i have to remove the half of the tags.
I have many post with almost 200 to 300 tags on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No too many tags do not make your site down. Please find if any plugin or theme function is using your resources too much. I think there is some custom query which is using your resources.